# AWS Glue Boto3 - Where can I find the list of the waiters?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I'm trying to kick off an AWS Glue ETL job in my Python script and check the status of it until the job finishes.

Initially I just did a simple while loop, which waits for 1 minute and checks the job status. Once the job finishes successfully, break the loop.  While researching more about this approach, I found out about this thing called 'waiter'.

But the thing is that even though the 'get_waiter' method is available for the Glue client, I do see any waiters.

So when I run this...

```
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
glue = boto3.client('glue')

print('s3 waiters')
print(s3.waiter_names)
print('glue waiters')
print(glue.waiter_names)
```

I get this...

```
s3 waiters
[u'bucket_exists', u'bucket_not_exists', u'object_exists', u'object_not_exists']
glue waiters
[]
```

So I'm wondering if there are actually waiters for AWS Glue. If so, were can I find them?

Some references I found:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.get_waiter

https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/clients.html#waiters

Comment: Since the result is an empty list when calling `print(glue.waiter_names)`, you've answered your own question. There are currently no waiters for Glue.

Comment: Did you find any way to replace the need of a waiter?

Comment: FYI, still no Glue waiters as of Oct 2021. However it looks like they could be added via a PR to botocore

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know more about a service's waiters there are three main ways to find out more details:

1. Check the boto3 documentation.  If a service has a waiter it will be listed there and how to use it.
2. Print the waiter names in the code just as you mentioned in your question.
3. Go to the [botocore data folder](https://github.com/boto/botocore/tree/develop/botocore/data) in github and check your specific services for information about the waiters available.

Edit:  for those that need a custom waiter for glue jobs

```
import boto3
from botocore.waiter import WaiterModel
from botocore.waiter import create_waiter_with_client

client = boto3.client('glue')
waiter_name = "JobRunCompleted"
waiter_config = {
    "version": 2,
    "waiters": {
        "JobRunCompleted": {
            "operation": "GetJobRun",
            "delay": 60, # Number of seconds to delay
            "maxAttempts": 30, # Max attempts before failure
            "acceptors": [
                {
                    "matcher": "path",
                    "expected": "SUCCEEDED",
                    "argument": "JobRun.JobRunState",
                    "state": "success"
                },
                {
                    "matcher": "path",
                    "expected": "FAILED",
                    "argument": "JobRun.JobRunState",
                    "state": "failure"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
waiter_model = WaiterModel(waiter_config)
glue_job_run_waiter = create_waiter_with_client(waiter_name, waiter_model, client)

glue_job_run_waiter.wait(JobName='my_job_name', RunId='my_run_id')
```